# Difficulty re-sizing array with reflection

Tags: c#, arrays, reflection, resize

I'm trying to re-size an arbitrarily-typed array with reflection. Here's my code:

```
public static void TestResizeArray()
{
    int[]
        ints;
    Array
        arrayOfInts;

    ints = new int[ 3 ];
    arrayOfInts = (Array) ints;
    ResizeArray( ref arrayOfInts, 5 );
    Debug.Assert( arrayOfInts.Length == 5 ); // passes
    Debug.Assert( ints.Length == 5 ); // FAILS <<<<<<<<<<<
}

public static void ResizeArray(
    ref Array
        theArray,
    int
        newSize )
{
    MethodInfo
        methodInfo,
        genericMethodInfo;
    object[]
        parameters;

    methodInfo = typeof( Array ).GetMethod(
        "Resize",
        BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Static );
    genericMethodInfo = methodInfo.MakeGenericMethod(
        theArray.GetType().GetElementType() );
    parameters = new object[] { theArray, newSize };
    genericMethodInfo.Invoke( null, parameters );
    theArray = (Array) parameters[ 0 ];
}
```

Calling the generic Array.Resize(...) function is working, in that parameters[0] contains the re-sized array, but it didn't change the theArray variable. Setting theArray to parameters[0] partially works, in that arrayOfInts in the calling function gets re-sized, but that seems to disconnect the ints array from arrayOfInts.

How can I change this so that the ints array gets resized?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ints` and `arrayOfInts` are two different reference variables which at first point to the same array instance.  The resizer returns a new array instance and assigns it to `arrayOfInts`.  The two references now point to different objects and there is no link between them.  If you want `ints` to point to the new object, you have to assign the new value back to it, or pass it directly to the resizer.

Comment: Thanks, Paul.  I understand.  But how can I pass an array of unknown type to a function without turning it into Array?

Comment: Or is the only way to make my ResizeArray function like Array.Resize, and make it generic, taking the element type?

Answer (score 1):

Let's look at Array.Resize method:

```
[ReliabilityContract(Consistency.WillNotCorruptState, Cer.MayFail)]
[__DynamicallyInvokable]
public static void Resize<T>(ref T[] array, int newSize)
{
  if (newSize < 0)
    throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("newSize", Environment.GetResourceString("ArgumentOutOfRange_NeedNonNegNum"));
  T[] objArray1 = array;
  if (objArray1 == null)
  {
    array = new T[newSize];
  }
  else
  {
    if (objArray1.Length == newSize)
      return;
    T[] objArray2 = new T[newSize];
    Array.Copy((Array) objArray1, 0, (Array) objArray2, 0, objArray1.Length > newSize ? newSize : objArray1.Length);
    array = objArray2;
  }
}
```

As you can see, there is an Array.Copy call. So, this method create new array and set pointer to this array into `array` parameter.
Your `ints` and `arrayOfInts` are different pointers to one array, and when you pass `arrayOfInts` to method, it revrites just this variable.